# How to load data from background thread, updating the UI asynchornously

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, lazy-loading

I have create a class `asyncTask` inside a `FragmentActivity` class:

```
    class aysncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    assert(filterfiles != null);
                    while( !searchDone.getValue() )
                    {
                            filterfiles.searchTargetFile(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/");
                            publishProgress();      //Doesn't work here.
                    }
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params)
            {
                    UpdateUI();                     //Only executes as the search is done.
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
            }
    }
```

`filterfiles.searchTargetFile(~)` function searches the local data, adding them to an `ArrayList: cachedData`. But I can't wait for the searching is done and then update the UI. The user will wait too long.
But I don't know where to put the updating UI code.
It can't be inside the method `onPostExecute(Void result)`, because I still have to wait the searching is done.

It can't also be inside the method `onProgressUpdate(Void params)`, because once I call `filterfiles.searchTargetFile(~)`, it will search the matched files in local system. Only when the search is done, it will call `publishProgress()`.

What comes into my mind is creating another thread observing the `cachedData`, once a file is found, I will add the file and updating the UI.

But I don't know how to do? Is this a good practice?
Please provide some suggested solution! I have spend two days in this issue.

**Update**
    I design a mechanism to implement loading data and updating UI asynchronously. Current
searchTargetFile code:

```
 public void searchTargetFile(String path)
    {   
            File dirRoot= new File( path );  
            File[] dirOrFile= dirRoot.listFiles();

            if( dirOrFile == null) return;
            for( File f : dirOrFile )
            {   
                    if( f.isDirectory() )
                    {   
                            searchTargetFile( f.getAbsolutePath() );
                    }   
                    else                        
                    {   
                            for(String extName: filterFileExt)
                            {   
                                    if( f.getName().endsWith(extName) )
                                    {   
                                            newDisplayFile= new DisplayFile(new String( f.getAbsolutePath() ), f.length());
                                            this.searchedDisplayFile.add(newDisplayFile);
                                    }   
                            }   
                    }   
            }   
            this.searchDone.setValue(true); 
    }
```

Where *newDisplayFile* is the item will be inserted into the *searchedDisplayFile*.

*Question:

1. How can I rewrite the search code by adopting thread so that I can `pause` and `resume` it. 
   Will `wait()` and `notify()` work?
2. Where should put `wait()` and `notify()` code in **aysncTask** class?

Any other better approach is appreciated!!!

Comment: The right way to do it is in both onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.  Both will be called on the UI thread, so they can touch the UI and they won't have synchronization issues.

Comment: so you should define to re-write your filterfiles.searchTargetFile method, using some paging technique

Comment: No, the scenario I want is as some files were found, update the UI immediately. One thread is responsible for searching data, and another is observing the searched data, then updating the UI

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam  What is `paging technique`? Any exmaple? How to implement the `searchTargetFile` really wore me out.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial about [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)?

Answer (score 0):

So I will add my answer here for your comment, since a comment could not show a code snippet.

Because I have no idea how your data looks like, so let's suppose that you have an indexed databased, and you want to do a search over your whole database, get a list of them. The idea of paging is to search for a limited items, save the offset for future use meanwhile update your list with those searched items. for example (pseudo code):

```
int max_items = 10;
int offset = 0;
while(searchable) {
    List<Items> items_ = searchFromOffset(offset); // this will return up to 10 items each time
    update(items_); // call the progressUpdate here
    offset += items_.size(); // next time you will search from next "page"
    searchable = checkForFinish(); // return a boolean value showing if the searching is finish or not
}
```

The real problem maybe more complex, but the general idea is as shown above. This will also help you save memory for each query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea about how to implement `searchFromOffset()` method?
Should I put the search method in a `Runnable Class`? Any examples is appreciated!

Comment: Well its behaviour is the same as what your "searchTargetFile" do, but it will just return a number of items/files once, not all of them. We repeat the call so that you save memory, you can update the result while search for more items. I guess you use an Cursor to move through your whole file list, so try to "pause" your Cursor somewhere, save the position, update the file list for this time, then start the next search from that position.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it can work. However, I don't know how to `pause` my searching method. I wonder that to put the search method in a thread may work or not?

Comment: Could you add the code for your searchTargetFile() method in your question? It might help others to know what have you tried.

Comment: Ok, but can you wait for some time? Simply to say, The implementation is just a `recursive approach`. It will search all items, if it is a directory, it will go deeper to find, otherwise the file will be added to a `ArrayList`. IT CAN"T be paused or stopped. Once the search starts, it has to go through the whole local file system. I think it's the major problem. I will try to solve it by implement the searching method on a thread. So please wait. Thanks.

Comment: If no more available suggestion is provided. I will delete this post and post a new one which is modified.

Comment: well you can think about it. but since the problem is the same (right), i'll try to find a work around. by the meantime, I'm thinking of using 2 or more thread to provide an asynchoronous task.

Answer (score 0):

I use **onProgressUpdate(progressValue);** instead of **publish progress**. That works pretty well for me.

Comment: onProgressUpdate() and publishProgress() work in pair. You publish something from background, then the onProgressUpdate() will use that to update the progress.